# Can I store a JavaScript Object in a mySQL database?

Tags: javascript, database

I am gathering data from a webpage visitor and putting it into a JavaScript object I create.  But later I want to be able to reference the data they entered.

I have access to a MySQL database, so is there a way for me to store this object there?

I want to try and keep it in the object format instead of breaking it up into its separate parts.

Comment: You can serialize the object and store that in a database.

Comment: Why store the object?  why not just store the value?

Answer (score 19):

Store a `JSON.stringified` version of your object in the database, then `JSON.parse` it when you want the object back again. It would look something like this:

```js
var myObj = {some: data, other: stuff};
var myObjString = JSON.stringify(myObj);
// store string in mySQL database here

// load string from database
var myJSONString = //mySQL database call
var myLoadedObj = JSON.parse(myJSONString);
```

Comment: You can add `<!-- language: lang-js -->` to let the SO system know what language highlighting it should use.

Comment: my question is: is this a standard practice that is ok or should we steer from it?

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't, at least not as it is.

You might be able serialise it to a string. If it consists entirely of arrays, simple objects, and the other data types supported by the [JSON format](http://json.org/) (which it probably will do if it is user supplied data (the main exception being if binary files are uploaded)), then you could use a JSON serializer to do so. Modern browsers provide the [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for this purpose and [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) will polyfill for older browsers. You could then store the string in the database.

Not breaking it into separate parts does throw away the many of the advantages of using a relational database though (i.e. the relationships and the ability to perform useful searches).

Answer (score 2):

Just store it as a JSON object in a field using the varchar or text data type.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSON.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)  You can use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to serialize form data and send it off to the server.  Also you could just use plain old forms, and process input on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Actually It can be done.

```
con.connect(function(err){
  var sql = "INSERT INTO books SET ?";  //books -- <tablename>
  if(err) console.dir("Error: "+err.message);
  var values = {
    "bname": "Elon Musk: Tesla, SpaceX, and the Quest for a Fantastic Future",
    "author": "Elon Musk",
    "genre": "Technology",
    "bookcount": "5"
  };
  con.query(sql, [values], function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.dir("Successfully inserted the row in table.");
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

But, along with this you have to satisfy these points,

- `value` should be object i.e., `value={ "name":"property" }`
- It should not be an array i.e., `values = [{}, {}]`
- **Imp.** - It should not have primary id column.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @kisore This is not exactly OP needs.

Comment: OP means? and then what do they exactly need?